# Are the relativistic effects of gravity strictly due to spacetime 'curvature'?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, curvature

I happen to live on an infinite flat Earth.  It has a constant uniform gravitational field extending above it.  Don’t I still observe relativistic effects such as light not traveling in straight lines, even though there doesn’t seem to be any spacetime 'curvature' involved anywhere?

Comment: Are you associating the curvature of spacetime with the "curvature" of the Earth (i.e. the fact that the Earth is more or less spherical)? Keep in mind that "popular" depictions of spacetime as being a mattress that is deformed by masses is very misleading. ([Mandatory xkcd](https://xkcd.com/895/))

Comment: additionally, you'd have spatial curvature in the z direction in a model like this.

Comment: I'm setting up a scenario where the gravitational field has zero curvature and then assuming that spacetime must also have zero curvature.  Your're right, it's indeed possible that the z-direction has some curvature but it's not clear to me what the mechanism would be or whether that curvature would be significant or important to the relatiivistic effects.

Comment: Good question Roger!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I happen to live on an infinite flat Earth. It has a constant uniform gravitational field extending above it.

It's an unrealistic scenario, but I'm sure we've all heard of it. If the massive body is contrived as an "infinite plane", the strength of the gravitational field doesn't diminish with distance. See this mathspages article for some details: https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath530/kmath530.htm

> Don’t I still observe relativistic effects such as light not traveling in straight lines, even though there doesn’t seem to be any spacetime 'curvature' involved anywhere?

Yes you do. Light curves downwards wherever there's a gradient in gravitational potential. Or, if you prefer, wherever there's a "spacetime gradient". In the traditional rubber sheet depiction associated with [Riemann curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor), light curves wherever the plot has a slope:

[image]
CCASA image by Mysid, see [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Spacetime_lattice_analogy.svg)

Spacetime curvature is needed for a real gravitational field because without it, the plot above could never get off the flat and level. This is why spacetime curvature is a  "defining feature" of a real gravitational field. Unfortunately there's a bit of a myth that's grown up wherein people tend to say "light follows the curvature of spacetime", but that's not right, as your question demonstrates.

Comment: that link seems valuable.  I can't follow the math, but it seems to be saying that there really is no satisfactory solution to the 4D Einstein field equations for this scenario which only involves two dimensions (time and distance from the plane).

Comment: It isn't a real scenario, so if there's no satisfactory solution that's understandable. The important point is that the force of gravity is associated with the first derivative of potential (the gradient), not the second derivative of potential (the curvature). The tidal force is associated with that. I like this eassay: https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0204044 .

Comment: Again the link is very helpful and quite readable!  I feel somewhat vindicated in thinking that gravitation is associated with a spacetime gradient. But I appreciate that a uniform gradient can only be achieved approximately over a limited region and, in fact, cannot even exist without support from a 'surrounding' region where spacetime is curved.

Comment: You should feel vindicated. A uniform gradient is approximately achieved in the room you're in, because your measurement of g at the ceiling is the same as your measurement of g at the floor. So there's no discernible spacetime curvature, but your pencil still falls down. Here's another reference, from the Einstien digital papers: https://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol7-trans/177

Answer (score 2):

This is a little bit of a semantic discussion: what qualifies as a “relativistic effect”.

Yes, light would follow a curved path, but light also could curve under Newtonian gravity. The relativistic deflection of light around the sun is twice the Newtonian prediction. In your uncurved spacetime they would be the same. So it is unclear to say if this is a relativistic effect or not.

There would also be time dilation. Time dilation is not explicitly part of Newtonian gravity, but Newtonian gravity is compatible with the equivalence principle. It is possible to derive gravitational time dilation from the equivalence principle. So it is also difficult to say if this is a relativistic effect.

I think a case could be made either way, but in the end whether or not you call them relativistic effects, the fact remains that there are many interesting gravitational effects in flat spacetime

Comment: I think my spacetime is uncurved but I assume it has a spacetime gradient because of the presence of the field. I was hoping to conclude that the first order effect of matter is to create a spacetime gradient and that although inevitably there will be some curvature somewhere that's not main driver.

Comment: @RogerWood: What is “a spacetime gradient” you are assuming to exist in your spacetime?

Comment: @Roger Wood the spacetime you describe has a Riemann curvature tensor which is 0 everywhere above the plane of mass. I have no idea what you mean by “spacetime gradient”.

Comment: @A.V.S. & Dale. Thanks, that's exactly the point I'm probing. I'm desperately trying to interpret this in some simple geometric terms. By gradient I mean some property of spacetime that varies linearly with distance from the mass plane (time dilation?).

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to imagine how a very big flat earth could not collape under its own gravity, becoming spherical. Maybe it is the case of say that spacetime curvature is a consequence of gravity instead of its cause.

But even on our spherical earth, GR tends to SR when spacetime interval tends to zero. It is the case for example of a radius of 4 km around (approximately the horizon line) and less than 1 km above us, for time intervals smaller that 1 minute. Everything passes in this case as we were is a ship upwards at an acceleration $g$. So all relativistic effects are there, but only SR equations are necessary.

Comment: My flat earth is infinite in extent so there are no in-plane fields to cause it to collapse.  If my flat earth is very large but finite in size, I will make it thin and taper the edge slightly so that the gravitational field remains finite everywhere and the pressure in the middle doesn't become excessive.